# Terminated due to timeout for my hacker rank solution

Tags: java, arrays, performance, collections

Hello all please check the problem[HackerRank Problem Statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/migratory-birds/problem)

This is my solution for the above problem(link)

```
static int migratoryBirds(List<Integer> arr) {
    int ar[]=new int[arr.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
        ar[i] = Collections.frequency(arr,arr.get(i));
        // ar[i] = obj.occuranceOfElement(arr,arr.get(i));
    }
    int maxAt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        maxAt = ar[i] > ar[maxAt] ? i : maxAt;
    }
    return arr.get(maxAt);
}
```

**my code is unable to handle when the array size is bigger,example 17623 elements in array**.

> Terminated due to timeout

The problem is in the second for loop which iterates over the array and gives me the index of the largest number in the array.**Is there any other way that I could increase the performance.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in this part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    ar[i] = Collections.frequency(arr, arr.get(i));
```

This is **O(N²)**: `Collections.frequency()` iterates over whole list to calculate frequency for only one element. Manually, you can iterate over the list to calculate frequencey for all elements.

Moreover, ther're only 5 birds, so you need only 5 length array.

```
static int migratoryBirds(int[] arr) {
    int max = 1;
    int[] freq = new int[6];

    for (int val : arr)
        freq[val]++;

    for (int i = 2; i < freq.length; i++)
        max = freq[i] > freq[max] ? i : max;

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the call to Colletions.frequency, which is an O(N) operation. When you call it from inside a loop it becomes O(N²) and that consumes all your time.

Also, are you sure which implmentation of List you receive? You call list.get(i) which might also be O(N) if the implementation is a LinkedList.

The target of this exercise is to calculate the frequency of each value in one pass over the input. You need a place where you store and increase the number of occurrences for each value and you need to store the largest value of the input.

You have also skipped over a crucial part of the specification. The input has limits which makes solving the problem easier than you now think.

Comment: It is not a linked list, it is an Array list. And is there any other way or a method to get the occurance of a element in a Arraylist @Torben

Comment: The purpose of this exercise is for you to figure out the way. If you use a ready made solution there is no point in even taking the challenge. It'd be like riding a marathon in a car.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one:

```
static int migratoryBirds(List<Integer> arr) {
    int freq[]=new int[6];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
        ++freq[arr.get(i)];
    }
    int maxAt = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < freq.length; i++) {
        if (freq[i] > freq[maxAt]) {
            maxAt = i;
        }
    }
    return maxAt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can determine *the type number of the most common bird* in one loop. This has the time complexity O(n).

```
static int migratoryBirds(int[] arr) {
    int highestFrequency = 0;
    int highestFrequencyBirdType = 0;
    int[] frequencies = new int[5]; // there are 5 bird types

    for (int birdType : arr) {
        int frequency = ++frequencies[birdType - 1];
        if (frequency > highestFrequency) {
            highestFrequency = frequency;
            highestFrequencyBirdType = birdType;
        } else if (frequency == highestFrequency && birdType < highestFrequencyBirdType) {
            highestFrequencyBirdType = birdType;
        }
    }

    return highestFrequencyBirdType;
}
```

For each element in the array `arr` we update the overall `highestFrequency` and are storing the corresponding value representing the `highestFrequencyBirdType` . If two different *bird types* have the *highest frequency* the lower type (*with the smallest ID number*) is set.